# Spring Data Cassandra not able to register custom repository

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am on spring-data-cassandra 1.1.1.RELEASE and I am trying to create a custom repository. I got a repository like

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends TypedIdCassandraRepository<Entity, EntityKey>, EntityRepositoryCustom {    
}
```

and I got a EntityRepositoryCustom:

```
public interface EntityRepositoryCustom{
    TelemetryPoint getEntityByDeviceAndDate(Device device, DateTime dateTime);
}
```

and its impl:

```
public class EntityRepositoryImpl implements EntityRepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired
    CassandraOperations template;

    @Override
    public Entity getEntityByDeviceAndDate(Device device, DateTime dateTime) {
        Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from("entity");

        Clause deviceClause = QueryBuilder.eq("device_id", device.getDeviceId());
        Clause dateClause = QueryBuilder.eq("datetime", dateTime);
        select.where(deviceClause).and(dateClause);

        Entity one = template.selectOne(select, Entity.class);
        return one;
    }
}
```

when starting the spring boot application, it seems like it is not able to discover the custom repository impl class. I am ending up with exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1713)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
    ... 37 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:202)
    ... 42 more
```

Note that I am on JDK1.8_25. Similar JPA based custom repository does not have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [spring-boot GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1929) any custom repository which extends Spring Data's `Repository` don't need a `@Repository` annotation.

If this doesn't help, adding `spring.dao.exceptiontranslation.enabled=false` to my application.properties worked for me.

Comment: You and Michael ako Tecourt hit the nail on the head and helped me solve a similar issue.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `@Repository` annotation on your repository interface? In fact you should rather put some `@Component` flavor on top of the custom repository implementation (`EntityRepositoryImpl`) instead.